--headless is not working for Python selenium
This is a block of code of my project
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options  import Options
import time

def extract_data(self, usrname : str):

        self.edge_options  = Options()
        self.edge_options.add_argument("--headless")

        self.usrname = usrname
        service = Service(executable_path=r'C:\web\msedgedriver.exe')
        self.driver = webdriver.Edge(service=service)
        self.driver.get(f'https://leetcode.com/{usrname}/') 

I am using the --headless open also but the browser window is still opening instead of just working in background.
How to fix it?

You add --headless in edge_options, which is never been used. :P

self.driver = webdriver.Edge(service=service)

Change above to:
self.driver = webdriver.Edge(service=service, options=self.edge_options)


It is working but there is an issue.
My program uses selenium to extract some data from Leetcode and then shows it on the webpage using flask render HTML templates.
When the --headless started working (by making the changes) then the program stopped working like the frontend of the program is working, backend(Flask) is also working but there is some issue in the logic of data extraction after making the changes.
